# sftp client with cygwin, is it possible?

Tags: cygwin, sftp

Is there any sftp clieant for cygwin? From what I read on the web, all I can find is instruction on how to install the server/ how to use putty/ how to use filezilla.

Is there a terminal client for sftp then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sftp is part of Cygwin's openssh package. Just install that through Cygwin's [setup.exe](http://cygwin.com/setup.exe). You can search packages at http://cygwin.com/packages.